# Ajax Live Data Search with load_data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I combine these two javascript codes?

I'm not good in JavaScript so it looks scrambled for me

I'll work on PHP ...

The first for (Live Data Search) Search for keyword

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
})
;
</script>
```

The second is for (Load More Data on Page Scroll)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 var limit = 7;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_country_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_country_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

In my case I have millions of data , So how I can combine these two javascript codes? !

Comment: Looks like this is an issue in your PHP. If you're sending `limit` and `start`, your PHP may be ignoring them and sending back all the results.

Comment: Not a issue, I just want to merge these codes To work on one code

Comment: If I understand, you want to be able to perform a query for results that has a limited number of results. Is that right?